# Aligning Div with bullet list

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get my bullets properly aligned next to a div image.

Here is my Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tzhvdpj7/

From that example you can see my last set of bullet points are far underneath the other adjacent two.

HTML:

```
<body>
<img src="http://luvit.xoom.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Kabokov-INGO-MAURER-210x564.jpg" alt="Lamp" class="right" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<br>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<br>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> 


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 33%;">
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<br>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right {
   float: right;
   padding: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
}

.p {
   text-indent: 30pt;
}
```

Any help here anyone? Been stuck on this..

Comment: Don't use width:33% in last 3rd div

Comment: what is the output you need. Can you share a image/screenshot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the div's smaller, I made the width 28% but you could change that.

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
}

.p {
  text-indent: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://luvit.xoom.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Kabokov-INGO-MAURER-210x564.jpg" alt="Lamp" class="right" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <br>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  <br>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <div style="float: left; width: 28%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 28%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 28%;">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <br>
    </ul>
  </div>
```